# Concatenate multiple vue-loader require in a computed property to define a srcset attribute Vue.js (Nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, srcset

I need an advise please,

I'm still stuck after trying in a lot of ways to create a reusable picture element component supporting native lazyload with a fallback to Lazysizes.js library and accepting variable number of image source types and dimensions (in `<source>` and his `srcset` attribute).

To achieve this I was  looking to use multiple `require` in a computed method and these need to be concatenated before being returned form the method (because I need to `require` for every available images dimensions) but I hurted again to what I think is a `require` limitation.

The img dependancy isn't found because I think `require` aren't resolved as I was presuming. here's my code to help you understand:

```
// parent component
<picture-elem
  :name="`${img}`"
  :img-alt="`${alt}`"
  :formats="['webp','jpg']"
  :sizes="[['512x768', '2x'], ['256x384', '1x']]"
  :img-class="'product-img'"
  :lazy="lazyloadImg" //true of false depending the context
/>


//in PictureElem component <template>
  <picture>
    <source
      v-if="formats.indexOf('webp') != -1"
      :srcset="(!lazy) ? srcsetWebp : false"
      :data-srcset="(lazy && !loadingAttrSupport) ? srcsetWebp : false"
      type="image/webp"
    >
    ... // other sources element for every accepted image types
    <img ... //fallback img
  </picture>


//in script > computed methods, an example of the problematic part with webp
computed: {
  getSizesLength () {
    return this.sizes.length
  },
  srcsetWebp () {
    let srcset = ""

    //loop through the array of availaible images srcset sizes
    for (let i = 0; i < this.getSizesLength; i++) {
      // require ( [path] + [base name] + [dimension] + [targeted resolution or screen width]
      srcset += `${require(`@/assets/img/${this.name}-${this.sizes[i][0]}.webp`)} ${this.sizes[i][1]}`
      
      // if there is following sizes, add a comma (,)
      if (i < (this.getSizesLength - 1)) {
        srcset += ", "
      }
    }
    return srcset
  }
```

I always get with it:

```
Failed to compile with 1 errors

This dependency was not found:

* @/assets/img/img-name.webp in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/PictureElem.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

I tried also with "~/assets/img/.."
I guest the problem is with the concatenated `require` as my debugging checks confirmed me.

I also know that a regular

```
return `${require(`@/assets/img/${this.baseName}_480.jpg`)} 480w, ${require(`@/assets/img/${this.baseName}_800.jpg`)} 800w`
```

should work as explained here by Alexander Lichter:
https://blog.lichter.io/posts/dynamic-images-vue-nuxt/#bonus---using-srcset

This wasn't my first way and I tried different path inspired by my findings in many articles. This was my last hope to get all the flexibility and enough dryness I planned for this component...

I will try with a `<slot>` to define the exact `require`s in the component parent but I would really like to learn if is there a way to achieve what I wanted in the way I was trying or confirming that `required` can't be use in this way (concatenated).

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Use `static` instead `assets` https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/static/

Comment: @Mohsen it is not recommended as I won't get all the vue-loader assets handling benefits if I go with /static folder, without talking about the management that would be a bit more difficult with these separated important assets in Static and not with others files in /assets

Comment: Your code would work, but there's a simple typo in your template string -- it's missing a path separator after `@`: `@assets` should be `@/assets`.

Comment: @tony19 It was a syntax mistake, it's `@/assets` that is written in my code and I get the error, I edited my question to fix it, thank you to pointing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that my problem was elsewhere, a part that isn't showed in the question to simplify the comprehension but I discovered you can't `require` with string variable in the beginning of the path. I was calling like this:

```
${require(`${this.imagePath}${this.name}-${this.sizes[i][0]}.webp`)}
```

but it seems `require` can't resolve the path like this. Adding the path fixed the problem:

```
${require(`~/assets/img/${this.name}-${this.sizes[i][0]}.webp`)}
// @/assets also works but as it is deprecated in the Nuxt docs I replaced the pointer with "~" everywhere.
```

And watch out if you forget to write the complete path (like missing the `/img/` part) because `require` will try to get all files in the assets and will output an error for every assets like fonts files or any other that doesn't fit for vue-loader aka webpack loader (I think so).